# Showing PHP variable in Javascript - Security point

Tags: javascript, php, security, code-injection

Originally I had the following structure:

**index.html** file:

```
...
<script src="myfunctions.js" />
...
```

**myfunctions.js** file:

```
...
function one() {
....
}
function two() {
....
}
function three() {
....
}
```

That way I got over 2 500 lines of Javascirpt written but then I had to add a PHP variable to a function so I had to rename **index.html** to **index.php**, rename **myfunctions.js** to **myfunctions.js.php** and do the following changes:

**index.php** file:

```
...
<?php
    include("myfunctions.js.php");
?>
...
```

**myfunctions.js.php** file:

```
<script>
...
function one() {
....
}
function two() {
....
}
function three() {
....
}
function four() {
    var x = <?php echo $_conf['user_id'];?>
    console.log(x);
}
</script>
```

I have achieved my purpose of using PHP variable in JavaScript but I have noticed that the web page in the browser started to show all the included function, i.e. if in the first case when I was looking at the page with a debug tool or by saving that page on a disk I saw just some little JavaScript code contained in index.html but now looking at or saving the index.php file I see all the functions from myfunctions.js.php visible. Of course the visible content didn't change but the actual output got 2 500 lines longer. Would that be a security problem? Should I avoid this way of showing a PHP variable in JavaScript or I shouldn't be concern about it and leave it how it is?

My concern is that in the second case all my functions gets open so a malicious user can see all the server-side PHP scripts names and required parameters which gives more ways to attack.

Comment: Don't mix data and script. It looks like you were already doing this if you `got over 2 500 lines of Javascirpt written`. Convert your data to _JSON_ (in _PHP_ ) then apply your _JavaScript_ on the data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concern or issue here.  JavaScript files can be viewed by the client regardless of what you do.

Comment: @Paul S. No those are not data, all those are functions requesting different PHP scripts and showing the output

Answer (score 2):

The PHP code is processed on the server so all anyone will see if the output of that PHP. So your PHP code is still hidden.

If you're seeing PHP code in your HTML output then either your server is configured incorrectly or you have a syntax error which echo's out what you intend for the parser to process.

Comment: No, I don't see the PHP code, I just got the output page much bigger with all the included js functions.

Comment: If you don't want them all to be loaded at once, which is not necessarily a bad thing since you can have that file cached for performance, you can have your PHP script receive arguments for which functions to include for any given page and only output those.

Answer (score 0):

Using index.php is fine but you don't really want to do a PHP include of a JS file like that.

The simplest way to go about it is to include the JS file like you were doing

```
<script src="myfunctions.js" />
```

and then add a small amount of Javascript to the PHP file which outputs the user_id.

```
function userId() {
    return <?php echo $_conf['user_id'];?>
}
```

Then function four can access it like

```
function four() {
    console.log(userId());
}
```

Ideally you will want your functions as part of an Object or module.

Another approach would be for function four to query the server for the user_id and then cache it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Careful you aren't introducing a [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) vulerability. If `$_conf['user_id']` is an integer then you should be fine, but be careful of mixing client side and server side script like this. @Paul S's comment is the way to go.

See here for more tips https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet